# scala intersection with count

Tags: scala, count, intersect, rdd

I have a simple question, suppose I have 2 RDDs:

```
RDD1: [a,b,b,c,c,c,d]  RDD2:[a,b,c,d]
```

and I want to find out how many a,b,c,d are there such that the returned results should be something like:

```
RDD:[(a,b,c,d),(1,2,3,1)]
```

It can be easily done using Lists, but in RDD, I seem to have to collect them first into Array and do something like:

```
count(_==string)
```

is there something easier that I could work with?

Answer (score 1):

I have very Less knowledge about RDD or Spark. but in scala you can try something like this :

```
    val l1 = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    val l2 = List('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd')

  def f(l1: List[Char], l2: List[Char]):(List[Char],List[Int]) = {
    val count = l1.map {
      x => l2.count(_ == x)
    }.toList
    (l1, count)
  }

  f(l1,l2)
```

Output at REPL :

```
res0: (List[Char], List[Int]) = (List(a, b, c, d),List(1, 2, 3, 1))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, your method is what I currently have, but I imagined that the RDD operations will be more computation efficient, because I also need to use the results to join with other data that I have processed.